# Why can't i launch concurrent kernels with the same pointer?

Tags: cuda

When launching concurrent kernels with the same data pointer, i get an "error reading location" exception.

I can easily fix this problem with cudaDeviceSynchronize(), but i want to understand what goes wrong.

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

struct Small {
    int a = 0;
};

struct Big {
    Small* small;
};

__global__ void kernelA(Small* small) {
    // Do nothing
}
__global__ void kernelB(Small* small) {
    // Do nothing
}

void myFunc(Big* big) {
    kernelA << <10, 10 >> > (big->small);
    //cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    kernelB << <10, 10 >> > (big->small);
}


int main()
{
    Big* big;
    cudaMallocManaged(&big, sizeof(Big));
    cudaMallocManaged(&big->small, sizeof(Small));

    myFunc(big);

    return 0;
}
```

If i uncomment "cudaDeviceSynchronize();" it works, but i don't understand why it wont work either way.

I have read this issue which is similar, but not quite: [CUDA : kernel concurrency with common (shared) argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30706945/cuda-kernel-concurrency-with-common-shared-argument)

So what is going wrong, why can't two kernels have the same pointer?

*Additional information*

I am using Visual Studio to compile compute_52,sm_52 for windows

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux? Unified memory behavior differs depending on that.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio to compile compute_52,sm_52 for windows

Comment: Please edit your question with such information, don't put it in the comments.

Comment: nitpicking: I wouldn't call this "concurrent kernels".  In typical parlance that I am familiar with, and the way that terminology is used for the relevant [cuda sample code](https://github.com/NVIDIA/cuda-samples/tree/master/Samples/0_Introduction/concurrentKernels), that refers to kernels which can run *at the same time*.  Yours cannot.  Because they are launched into the same stream (the null stream, in this case), they will never run concurrently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be on windows, which is a [pre-pascal regime for managed memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307707/how-to-access-managed-memory-simultaneously-by-cpu-and-gpu-in-compute-capability/54313816#54313816), regardless of what GPU you are running on.

In this modality, as soon as you launch a kernel, all managed allocations become inaccessible to host code.  So `big` is a location in host memory, and therefore retrieving the pointer value of `big` is always legal in host code.  But what `big` points to in your case is managed memory.  To get that value, it's necessary to dereference `big` and retrieve a value offset from that pointer.  That dereference operation results in accessing a managed allocation, which is illegal in host code (in a pre-pascal regime, after a kernel launch, before any `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`).  The kernel launch process involves host code retrieval of the kernel arguments.

Therefore you are going to hit a seg fault.

And this doesn't have much to do with the "same pointer".  It has to do with managed allocations, that must be accessed from host code in pre-pascal regime.

Some fix ideas:

- as you already discovered, put a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` in between, which restores host-code accessibility to the managed allocation.
- switch to a demand-paged managed environment (linux, on Pascal or newer GPU).
- capture the pointer in question in a host variable, so that dereferencing of a managed pointer is not required for host code access at the point of the second kernel launch:

  ```
  Small *temp = big->small;
  kernelA << <10, 10 >> > (temp);  // or (big->small); here
  kernelB << <10, 10 >> > (temp);  // must use temp here
  ```

As an aside, not having a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` or other synchronizing function (like `cudaMemcpy()`) after the last kernel launch means that the process may get torn down before your kernels actually execute, but I assume you're just showing a minimal example here.  Still I would advise the inclusion of such.

Comment: *You appear to be on windows, which is a pre-pascal regime for managed memory, regardless of what GPU you are running on.*

Exactly the answer i was looking for, thank you!

Comment: If you are actually running on a `sm_52`, you would be in a pre-pascal regime whether on windows or linux.